# Correction of a sequence of bits on Python

Tags: python, classification

I have a sequence of bit on Python such as:

```
bits = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

This sequence is the output of a classifier for a test set, and therefore some bits may be missclassified. Logiacally speaking I am sure that there is an error if I see a sequence of bits which is shorter than (say) 4. Therefore if I get:

```
output = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

I know that the zeros in position 13 and 14 are supposed to be 1. Is there a library to perform a correction following this logic (that takes in input the output of my classifier and gives me the corrected sequence of bit)?
I am working on python.

Comment: Why both 13 and 14 should be 1 ? I can see why 13 should be 1 butq not 14. Assuming you want all consecutive sequences to be more than 1

Comment: Your question body honestly makes little sense to me. Can you define "okay" and "containing an error" sequences precisely? Also, are you trying to "classify" timesteps of discrete signals?

Comment: What I said is that if a sequence of bits (zeros or ones) is shorter than 4 then it is an error (each bit is a 200ms shift in time and a task cannot last less than 1 second).

Comment: what if u get this sequence: 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0. which bit should be converted to 1, number 5 or 9? (from the left)